# Inheritance calling superclass method java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes: B inherits form A and C form B. I want to call fun2() method form B class. So the user is asked to input value of x and y and then in class C I want to display the user's imput calling fun2() method. The programm displays x=0 y=0 no matter what user's imput is. How can I access value of x and y in class C ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          C ccc = new C();
          ccc.fun3();
    }

}
class A
{
    Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
        int x, y;
        public void fun1()
        {
            System.out.println("x= ");
            x=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("y= ");
            y=in.nextInt();
        }
}
class B extends A
{
    public void fun2()
     { 
        System.out.println("fun2");
        fun1();
    }

}
class C extends B
{
   B bb = new B();
    public void fun3()
    {
        bb.fun2();
        System.out.println("fun3");
        System.out.println("x= "+ x);
        System.out.println("y= "+ y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `B bb = new B();` from class `C`. And change `bb.fun2();` to `super.fun2();` (and the `super.` is *optional* - because of the `extends` a `C` **is-a** `B`)

**or** print the `x` and `y` from `bb` (where you have set them, currently your fields in class `C` are not set - thus to display the values that were set, you would need to access them from `bb`).

```
System.out.println("x= "+ bb.x);
System.out.println("y= "+ bb.y);
```